# How to Add custom CSS to my wordpress page and use that css only on my android app webview

Tags: php, android, css, wordpress

Iam trying to design a android app of my wordpress website www.pocketdoctors.in which is a Listings page(Not a Blog) so Iam using webview as main concept in my app but a lot of changes has to be made for an app view like Removing header and footer and menus etc. on App alone. Changes should not show up in Mobile browser.
Thank You If any One helped

Comment: How about using media queries to modify your layout on mobile?

Comment: can you give a sample to start it up. Thank you

Comment: In your main css file just add something like`@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}`, where you can target the width of the screen (in my example from 480px to 767px), and you can overwrite any default styling there, so that it will apply only between those window widths.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Have you considered just making your Wordpress site mobile friendly?

[WPTouch](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wptouch/) is one alternative.

Here are some others:

http://crunchify.com/top-3-wordpress-plugins-to-make-your-site-mobile-friendly/

Comment: Yeah i tried but it cant work for me .Iam using a mobile app with custom pages and custom menus and webview is to show what ever my client searches with 3 different variables like categories, Place, and Keyword. You can go through the website for reference.